# How to show a part of a page based on stateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a table with multiple rows, and each one of them has a `<td>`
called `ID`.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               ID
            </th>
            <th>
               XYZ
            </th>
            <th>
               XYZ
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="">10</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>
            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="3" class="more-info">
            <!-- I want to show this row if the $stateparams has an id === 10;  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="">120</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>
            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="3" class="more-info">
            <!-- I want to show this row if the $stateparams has an id === 120;  -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="">420</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>

            <td>
                XYZ
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="3" class="more-info">
                        <!-- I want to show this row if the $stateparams has an id === 420;  -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

When you click on an id, a request will be sent to the server to get data by that `ID`. The data will be displayed in the table row below the row with that `ID`. The click also updates the `url`, for instance from `localhost:3000/app` to `localhost:3000/app/420`.

How to show only the `table row` below the row that matches the `stateparams.id`? If you refresh the page(`localhost:3000/app/420`), it should be still shown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

**in Html:**

```
   <tr colspan="3" class="more-info" ng-if="CurrentID=='120'">
     <!-- I want to show this row if the $stateparams has an id === 120;  -->
  </tr>
```

**In JS**

```
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$stateParams) {

       $scope.CurrentID = 0;

      if($stateParams.id != undefined){

           $scope.CurrentID = $stateParams.id;

       }

    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I had done the same thing but had problem with page relaod.